# What is the best way to signal a loop to exit on a thread in Cocoa?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I have a method (let's call it run):

```
- (void)run
{
    // Do some initialisation

    // Loop until another thread signals it to exit
    while (SHOULD_STILL_LOOP) { ... }

    // Clean up code
}
```

And I call it with:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(run)];
```

What is the best way to implement SHOULD_STILL_LOOP?  Should I use an atomic property, a NSCondition, dispatch semaphore?

Perhaps some stackies can offer me some advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one way of doing this and that is using NSThread.

```
- (void)run:(id)obj
{
    while(![[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) { ... }
}

- (void)start
{
    self.thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                          selector:@selector(run)
                                            object:self.object];
    [self.thread start];
}

- (void)stop
{
    [self.thread cancel];
    self.thread = nil;
}
```